# RXJS Repeat query until a condition is met?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using an API that returns only a limited number of results, say 100.

I'd like to repeat a query until the return result set is `< 100` which would mean I've got the last result.

So it would go like this:

1. Make query
2. Is result set less than limit? If so, do again and append results.
3. Once result set is less than limit, emit the final result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the **expand** operator for a simple "conditional repeat" behavior.

Just for the example, instead of a result set I changed the query to return a number. The following keep querying until the retrieved number is less than 100

```js
const { defer, empty } = rxjs;
const { expand, toArray} = rxjs.operators;

const query$ = defer(async () =>  Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
   
query$
  .pipe(
    expand(result => result < 100 ? empty() : query$),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How would you limit the number of "repeat"s?

Answer (score 27):

We can also use the [repeat](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/repeat) operator:

```
this.queryData().pipe(
    repeat(),
    filter(data => this.checkLimit()),
    take(1)
).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Note: the `take(1)` is needed to stop the `repeat` loop.

If we need a delay between retries, we can do:

```
repeat({delay: 1000})
```

Comment: This method is elegant.

Comment: hi, is it possible to return boolean observable for filter. I have same situation but my condition return boolean observable, this checklimit returns observable. can we filter with observable here

Comment: I assume it could be done like this:
```
this.queryData().pipe(
    repeatWhen(obs => obs),
    concatMap(data => this.checkLimitObs(data).pipe(map(test => ([test, data])))),
    filter(([test, data]) => test),
    take(1)
).subscribe(([test, data]) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I think you can use `find(checkLimit)`. It's basically the same as `filter()` and `take(1)` together.

Comment: @ebrehault since this method is deprecated, could you write the same with `repeat()`

Comment: Add throwIfEmpty as well to handle the case when filter always return false. Otherwise your subscriber will not be notified.

Answer (score 6):

```
 stop$: Subject = new Subject();

 query$.pipe(takeUntil(this.stop$)).subscribe( result => {
    if(result < limit) 
       this.stop$.next();
       this.stop$.complete();
     }
   else {
      process result, i.e append somewhere...
   }
 });
```

Note his is the RxJs 6 syntax. For readability you can extract the subscribe logic in a method.

Maybe working with takeWhile is easier in this case:

```
doQuery: boolean = true;

 query$.pipe(takeWhile(()=> this.doQuery).subscribe( result => {
    if(result < limit) 
       this.doQuery = false;
     }
   else {
      process result, i.e append somewhere...
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
You can also use RXJS Interval with TakeWhile operator. Here is the sample code

In Component:

return Observable
  .interval(250)
  .flatMap(() => this.getQueryData())
  .takeWhile(data => this.checklimit(data))
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result);

getQueryData(){
   // HTTTP API call 
}

checklimit(){
  // return true/false
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, interval() approach doesn't account for the response time. We are re-sending http request each 250ms. But the response time itself might be longer than 250ms. There is no correlation between completing previous call and starting new one.