# How to force an observable to always emit after some time idle

Tags: typescript, ionic5, rxjs-observables

I have an app that should scan for specific ble devices. The scan function I use keeps scaning all devices and should even report duplicates (the same device can be scanned multiple times). To organize the scanned data, I created an observable that emits all devices found in a list and remove the ones that were not scanned within certain time:

```
public findMyDevice() {
    let my_devices: any[] = [];

    return this.ble.startScan().pipe(
        filter(
            (device) => this.deviceIsMyDevice(device)
        ),
        map(
            (device) => {
                device = this.treatData(device);
                my_devices =  my_devices.filter((dev) => dev.id != device.id); // in case it is already in the list
                let now = new Date();
                device.time_scan = now;
                my_devices.push(device);
                my_devices.sort((a, b) => a.sn - b.sn);
                my_devices = this.removeOldDevices(my_devices); // remove scans older than 5 seconds
                return my_devices;
            }
        )
    )
}
```

It works fine if there is at least one device ON nearby.

Problem is: if all devices are turned off, my scan function never emits and the call to removeOldDevices is never made... That way, some old devices are kept in the list...

I tried to solve it adding to my pipe:

```
timeoutWith(3000,
    of().pipe(
        map(
            () => {my_devices = this.removeOldDevices(my_devices); return my_devices}
        )
    )
)
```

but it seems to finish the subscription after the timeout. What is the best way to solve this? How can I force the observable to emit after some idle time without finishing the subscription? Is there any other rxjs operator to help with this situation?

Comment: Probably this is what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/51640489/2333617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is an interval stream.

interval(3000), creates a stream that emits a number every 3 seconds.

```
const intervalUpdate$ = interval(3000).pipe(
    map(_ => my_devices = this.removeOldDevices(my_devices))
)
```

This would remove old devices every 3 seconds. Side note: remember that if you never unsubscribe, this will go forever. Then you can (for example) use this with merge:

```
const scanUpdate$ = this.ble.startScan().pipe(
    filter(
    [... more code here]
);
return merge(intervalUpdate$, scanUpdate$);
```

If you want to get more sophisticated, you can use switchMap to mix an interval with your stream so that a new timer gets started each time a device is emitted:

```
// Make a fake object so we can trigger switchMap immediately and get our
// interval/timer stream engaged. There's probably a better way to do this.
const falseStart = {isFakeDevice: true};
// Compose the return stream
return this.ble.startScan().pipe(
    filter(device => this.deviceIsMyDevice(device)),
    // startWith() as a hack to make sure out interval stream gets 
    // switched into right away
    startWith(falseStart),
    // switchMap will create a new stream that emits the given value
    // (normally a device, but will be 'falseStart' to start) and then  
    // emits null every 3 seconds. That logic is restarted every time a  
    // new device arrives, effectively resetting the interval stream
    switchMap(device => 
        interval(3000).pipe(
            mapTo(null),
            startWith(device)
        )
    ),
    // Filtering out our hacked falseStart object; we don't want it
    filter(device => !device?.isFakeDevice),
    map(device => {
        // Your code here, remembering that device might be null if it
        // was triggered by the interval stream
        [...]
        return this.removeOldDevices(my_devices);
    })
);
```

The downside to the more 'sophisticated' approach is that the very first value passed through isn't really desirable. I would probably replace falseStart with 'null' and not bother filtering it out. You'll get an immediate response when you subscribe to this stream, but that's generally not much of a performance hit and might even be desirable.

The upside to the "sophisticated" approach is that as long as you're still finding devices, the interval(3000) may never need to emit a value. This might save you a lot of performance depending on how expensive this.removeOldDevices() is.

Comment: As a side note, since you're returning an array, what you probably want is reduce