# Cannot finish a race with timer in RxJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, rxjs

```js
race(
  timer(2000).pipe(mapTo(1)),
  timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(2)),
).toPromise().then(r => console.log(r))
```

Code above will output `2`.

If I have an action that I try to repeat until condition is met but ignore it if it takes too long, then I take an approach in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51644077

The problem is that `race` never finishes with the shortest function. The `longActionObservable` repeats until the condition is met and `empty()` is called.

```js
const o = longActionObservable();
race(
  o.pipe(expand(v => v < 100 ? empty() : o)), // no toArray because I do not need result
  timer(2000),
).toPromise()
```

This code does not return a promise that will ever resolve. I'm wondering why is this approach so fragile to this kind of behavior? If there's one observable `timer(2000)` that most surely ends, why doesn't race end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an important point about [`race`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race):

> The observable to emit first is used

This means that if first emission of `longActionObservable` occurs before the timer, then timer is not used, regardless of how long the "expand" observable takes to complete.

> no toArray because I do not need result

Even though you don't need the result, `toArray` actually makes this work as you wish because it will not allow any emissions until your "expand" observable completes.  Instead of using `toArray`, you could use [`reduce`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce) instead:

```js
race(
  o.pipe(
    expand(v => v < 100 ? empty() : o), 
    reduce(() => undefined)
  ),
  timer(2000),
)
.toPromise()
```

> If there's one observable timer(2000) that most surely ends, why doesn't race end?

The only reason race will not end is because the chosen source (*first observable to emit*) does not complete.  Check the emissions of your expand observable to see why it isn't completing:

```js
  o.pipe(
    expand(v => v < 100 ? empty() : o),
    tap(v => console.log('expand: ', v)),
    reduce(() => undefined)
  ),
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67854241?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) you can play around with :-)